# UASM with undeclared conversion is not working

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm

The system is crashing in this assembler development.I think some of these prototypes are wrong. However, I don't know what exactly the problem is.

```
   ;        uasm  -elf64 tagex.asm
    ;        gcc -o out  tagex.o -fno-pie -no-pie `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
     
OPTION LITERALS:ON

    gtk_init                    PROTO  :VARARG
    gtk_text_view_new           PROTO  :VARARG
    gtk_text_view_get_buffer    PROTO  :VARARG
    gtk_text_buffer_create_tag  PROTO  :VARARG
.DATA
        WWatch                  qword    0
        WWatchBuffer            qword    0
.CODE
    main PROC
        invoke gtk_init,0,0
        invoke gtk_text_view_new
        mov WWatch              ,rax
        invoke gtk_text_view_get_buffer,WWatch
        mov WWatchBuffer        ,rax
         invoke gtk_text_buffer_create_tag,WWatchBuffer, "rtl_quote",\
                                  "foreground", "green",\
                                  "wrap_mode", 2,\
                                  "direction", 2,\
                                  "indent", 30,\
                                  "left_margin", 20,\
                                  "right_margin", 20,\
                                  0
             invoke gtk_text_buffer_create_tag ,WWatchBuffer,"red_foreground","foreground", "red", 0                                 
        xor rax,rax
        ret
    main ENDP
end
```

Comment: Crashing on what?  Use a debugger to find which instruction crashes, so you can include that part of your [mcve], along with the code.  I assume this is on GNU/Linux of some sort?

Comment: @PeterCordes  Ubuntu linux. [https://github.com/samsung-191t/coding/blob/master/asm%20error].  `0x004011f7      sub     rsp, 8`

Comment: It crashes on the very first instruction?  That's not even a memory access.  Perhaps you got your directives wrong and your code is in a non-executable section?  I've never even heard of UASM so IDK if `.CODE` is the right directive like I think MASM uses.  Also, [edit] your question to include all the details you have.

Comment: The error occurs while calling the second function : gtk_text_buffer_create_tag
I tried the code  without this line:" sub rsp, 8", and I noticed the difference

Answer (score 1):

If the invoked function is non-leaf function, you must create a shadow space of 32 bytes on the stack (sub rsp,32) and restore it (add rsp,32) before you exit your code.

The first three invoked functions return normally, so they are probably the leaf ones.

Function "gtk_text_buffer_create_tag" is obviously a non-leaf, so it writes to the shadow space (above the rsp+8, where the params are), so it overrides some parameters. There are pointers to the strings, so overriding them might be the issue.

By adding 8 to the rsp to make the function works, it must writes only to the rsp+8 space (above the return address, the empty space created by adding 8 to the rsp), so no parameter is overridden. That would be my best guess with out having a chace to debug the function.

Comment: The x86-64 System V ABI doesn't have shadow space.  That's only part of the Windows x64 calling convention.  But we can see the question is using `uasm -felf64`, which presumably means this will be linked into a native GNU/Linux executable on the querent's Ubuntu system.